# PHP compression

Tags: php, compression

I need to compress/decompress in php and compress/decompress it in C++
I know about gzinflate/gzdeflate, bzcompress/bzdecompress and etc. - it's all one method, just with different wrappers
But I need any another method, with C++ there's no problem, but I have no access to extensions on PHP, so I can use only inbuilt package
Can I access using installed libraries?

Installed extensions:

```
[0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre
[6] => zlib [7] => bz2 [8] => calendar [9] => ctype [10] => curl [11] => hash
[12] => fileinfo [13] => filter [14] => gettext [15] => gmp [16] => SPL
[17] => iconv [18] => json [19] => session [20] => standard
[21] => Reflection [22] => Phar [23] => SimpleXML [24] => mbstring
[25] => tokenizer [26] => cgi-fcgi [27] => bcmath [28] => dba
[29] => dom [30] => ftp [31] => gd [32] => imap [33] => exif
[34] => mcrypt [35] => mysqli [36] => mysql [37] => mysqlnd
[38] => PDO [39] => pdo_mysql [40] => sqlite3 [41] => pdo_sqlite
[42] => posix [43] => soap [44] => sockets [45] => xmlreader
[46] => xmlrpc [47] => xml [48] => xmlwriter [49] => xsl
[50] => zip [51] => intl [52] => rar [53] => hostprotect
[54] => mhash [55] => ionCube Loader [56] => Zend Guard Loader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you have PHP `zip` extension. Hence you can use [bzip2](http://php.net/manual/en/bzip2.examples.php), which will return a compressed version of the input data. It is not a wrapper of gzip, It is entirely different compression algorithm.

Eg:

```
 <?php    
  $filename = "/tmp/testfile.bz2";
  $str = "This is a test string.\n";

  $bz = bzopen($filename, "w");
  bzwrite($bz, $str);
  bzclose($bz);  
?>
```

[Full Reference Bzip2 Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bzip2.php)

Comment: Thank you for reply
Gzip is a wrapper over deflate
Unfortunately I need another algorithm

Comment: Thank you, I thought that bzip2 is wrapper too, but it's another algorithm
I'll tag your message right
Thank you again